# Keeping referenced data organized after sorting

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I run a Cub Scout Pack, and when scouts fundraise, a portion of the money they earn can go into an "account". Money can then be used to pay for scouting-related activities.

I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet to keep track of when scouts earn money, and when they've used it.

[Here's what I have so far](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GN9Ie3x77_LqdBglZP4Luse2VamcPbSZzDksvoBUlr8/edit?usp=sharing).

It seems to be working fine. The problem is that if I sort any of the tabs by the Scout's name, the data in the relevant columns doesn't stay sorted and attached to the actual scout.

Any tips on how I can best set this spreadsheet up to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not blindly trust that each name will continue to be at the same row number on every sheet. Use a `vlookup()` or `filter()` instead. Try this:

`=sum( iferror( filter(Earned!B$2:ZZ, Earned!A$2:A = A2) ) ) - sum( iferror( filter(Used!B$2:ZZ, Used!A$2:A = A2) ) )`

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice but it's still not working. I updated the link above with my modifications. The scout names are now driven off a tab called "Scouts". If I insert "Scout D" between C and E, it messes with all the inputs on "Earned" and "Used". Perhaps I didn't understand your directions?

Comment: The formula I gave above seems to give the "correct" results. The problem is that your `=arrayformula(Scouts!A2:A)` formula will make scout names misaligned with the amounts in 'Earned' and 'Used'. That issue is different from the sort issue you asked about. Replace the array formula with regular text strings to avoid the issue. See this [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).